# Convert Timestamp to a Value for different Timezones in Javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have different timestamps and a timezones coming from an API as an object. Example:

```
{{'ts' : 1521311400000},
 {'tz' : 'GMT+01:00'}}
```

How can I convert the timestamp to a human readable Date in that timezone using `toLocaleTimeString()`? I have tried to pass the timezone inside the `options` object as the value for `timeZone` as stated [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString) but I get an `invalid time zone in DateTimeFormat()` Error and cant figure out how the correct Format should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like another option, you could try this:

```
function init() {
  function formatFixedTimeZone(ts, tz) {
    let offsetStr = tz.replace(/:/g, '');
    let reverseOffset = offsetStr.replace(/[-+]/, sign => sign === '+' ? '-' : '+');
    let time = new Date(ts);
    let timeStr = time.toUTCString().replace('GMT', reverseOffset);

    time = new Date(Date.parse(timeStr));
    timeStr = time.toLocaleString('en-US', {
      timeZone: 'UTC', // Don't change this from UTC for other time zones.
      weekday: 'short',
      month: 'short',
      day: 'numeric',
      year: 'numeric',
      hour: '2-digit',
      minute: '2-digit',
      second: '2-digit'
    }) + ' ' + tz;

    return timeStr;
  }

  let timeDisplay = document.getElementById('time');

  function tick() {
    let nowStr = formatFixedTimeZone(Date.now(), 'GMT+01:00');

    timeDisplay.textContent = nowStr;
  }

  setInterval(tick, 1000);
}
```

Plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/Gk6SOLwpWqfoT5gHlCrb?p=preview

This displays a running count of the current time in a fixed time zone, but I've tried to write it in such a way that if you aren't using the current time, but the ts and tz values from your API, it shouldn't be too hard to adapt this to your needs and to different output formatting.

Answer (score 2):

To get that kind of flexibility in formatting dates, you'll probably want to look into [Moment](https://momentjs.com/) and [Moment Timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/).

Comment: I have looked into moment.js but using a whole library just for that one case is imho a bit of an overkill